# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'hub'

Tags: pytorch

```
import torch
model = torch.hub.list('pytorch/vision')
```

My pytorch version is 1.0.0, but I can't load the hub, why is this?

Answer (score 3):

You will need `torch >= 1.1.0` to use `torch.hub` attribute.

Alternatively, try by downloading [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/hub.py) `hub.py` file and then try below code:

```
import hub
model = hub.list('pytorch/vision', force_reload=False)
```

**Arguments:**

`github:` Required, a string with format `repo_owner/repo_name[:tag_name]` with an optional tag/branch. The default branch is `master` if not specified.
Example: `pytorch/vision[:hub]`

`force_reload:` Optional, whether to discard the existing cache and force a fresh download.
Default is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

deinstall torch

reinstall torch==1.9.0, torchvision==0.10.0
and then install the necessary requirments.txt again